# Error while indexing data in another table and passing it to match another query

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have these tables: (unwanted columns were truncated in the question)

rooms:
**room_id | room_type_id | room_number**

room_types:
**room_type_id | room_type | room_type_default_price**

reservations:
**reservation_id room_type | checkin | checkout**

1. When user searches for available rooms by entering desired room type, arrival date, departure date it, the available room types must be populated in a dropdown. However there are two problems, one is known and one is unknown. **Below code returns nothing but an "array to string conversion error" on page (View) load.**
2. The known problem is that, the dropdown for the room type is filled with data from room_types table as well. For JS/jQuery calculation I have concatenated room_type column and room_type_default_price column on populating. So the generated HTML is like this:

Double Room

Therefore the user input $room_type comes in as, for example "Double Room_20000" where originally no column data exists that way. In room types table, room_type column has "Double Room" though. How do I separate these two values and get room_type_id to $room_type_id ?

Model:

```
function searchRoomType($room_type) {
    $query = $this->db->query(" SELECT room_type_id FROM room_types WHERE room_type = '$room_type' LIMIT 1");
    return $query->result();

    //return $room_type_id;

    //print_r ($room_type_id);
}

function searchRooms($room_type, $start_date, $end_date, $tmpRoomNumber = array()) {
    $room_type_id = $this->searchRoomType($room_type);

    $query = $this->db->query(
        "SELECT a.room_number
        FROM rooms a LEFT OUTER JOIN (  SELECT room_number
                                        FROM reservations
                                        WHERE checkin >= '$start_date'
                                        AND checkout <= '$end_date'
                                        ) b
        ON a.room_number = b.room_number
        WHERE a.room_type_id = '$room_type_id'
        AND a.housekeeping_status = 'Clean'
        AND b.room_number is NULL
        GROUP BY a.room_type_id
        ORDER BY a.room_number ASC");

    if($query->num_rows()>0) {
        foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $tmpRoomNumber[$row['room_number']] = $row['room_number'];
        }
    }
    return $tmpRoomNumber;

}
```

Comment: on what line does the error point to?

Comment: searchRooms returns an array so where ever you are outputting the return of that function is the source of your Error

Comment: - Please make sure function searchRoomType() can return a $room_type_id, i'm not checking but the returned value seems query result object, not an id. 
- In function SearchRooms, there's no need to include $tmpRoomNumber as an parameter.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should change the function searchRoomType like this

```
function searchRoomType($room_type) {
    $query = $this->db->query(" SELECT room_type_id FROM room_types WHERE room_type = '$room_type' LIMIT 1");
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
      $room_type_i=$row->room_type_id;
    }
  return $room_type_id;
}
```